# Node.js and Passport Object has no method validPassword

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I'm using Node.js + Express + Passport to create a simple authentication(local)

and what I've reached so far that when a wrong username or password entered user is redirected to an error page

but when the user enters a correct username and password I get this error

```
node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:435
    throw err;
          ^
TypeError: Object { _id: 50b347decfd61ab9e9e6768f,
username: 'saleh',
password: '123456' } has no method 'validPassword'
```

I'm not sure what's wrong there

app.js (I removed the unnecessary code):

```
  var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

  app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});



var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'authTest');

var authSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  username: 'string',
  password: 'string'
});

var User = db.model('users', authSchema);


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});




app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login/error',

                                  })
);
```

---

and now in routes/login.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'authTest');

var authSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string'
});

var User = db.model('users', authSchema);

exports.index = function(req, res){
User.find(function (err, list) {
        res.render('login', { title: 'Usernames and Passwords', users: list,msg:""});
    });
};
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using

```
if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
}
```

but you haven't defined `validPassword` method. Attach it to your schema:

```
var authSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string'
});
authSchema.methods.validPassword = function( pwd ) {
    // EXAMPLE CODE!
    return ( this.password === pwd );
};
```

**EDIT** You've also incorrectly defined the schema. It should be:

```
var authSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```

Note that both `username` and `password` should be `String` type objects, not strings `"string"`, if you know what I mean. :)

Comment: Another question if you may.. can you recommend me a book or any resource to learn Node.js better ?

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh I don't know any Node.JS book. I've learned everything by constantly googling. Start with tutorial on [Node.JS main page](http://nodejs.org/). And then just google. Stackoverflow is a great source of knowledge as well. That's how I've learned it.

Comment: This is for Passport, though. Shouldn't there already be functionality for hashing passwords and checking them?

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you copied example from passportjs website, where Jared failed to mention how to implement it..

On the passport js github page he has another (simpler) example; he removed validPassword method altogether (line 18):

[Example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js)

```
if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
```

That's what I based my app on (using encryption) on top of it.

Comment: Thanks I really needed a simpler example and I've also contacted Jared to make a better documentation :)

Answer (score 5):

Also being a noob at this, it took me a whole day to figure this one out. I used the history from another one of Jared's example apps and some crypto advice from folks on here.

First off I made a method that generates a salt (a big random number which is stringified), uses the salt and the user's password to create a hash (with the help of the nodejs 'crypto' module), and finally stores both the salt and the hash every time before mongoose saves a new account.

```
//make hash
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();
    var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000)).toString(36);
    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(user.password + rand).digest("hex");
    user.password = hash;
    user.salt = rand;
    next();
});
```

For the verification I simply take the inputted password (at login) and attempt the make the same hash again using the salt. I then compare the stored hash to the new one and return true or false accordingly.

```
 // Password verification
    userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
      var testhash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password + this.salt).digest("hex");
      if(testhash === this.password) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: That moment when you realize this is a year old.

Comment: It's okay :) Thanks for the contribution

Comment: This answer should probably be updated because using md5 and `Math.random` is not secure.