# Why it throws user.validPassword is not a function Err?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am building node.js app and I using **Passport js**, I read Passport-local doumentation from it's official website and i used it's *local passport-strategy* and it throws *user.validPassword is not a function* Error!

**app.js**

```
require('./config/test')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**index.js**

```
router.get('/test', (req, res, next)=>{
  res.render('test');
});
router.post('/test',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/test',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

**config/test.js**

```
var passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../model/students');

module.exports = function () {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function (username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                }
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
}
```

> Node Version: 10.16.1
>
> Express Version: 4.16.1

Comment: it would throw that error because user.validPassword is not a function - where is it defined?

Comment: I copied that from it's official website, is it incorrect!!

Comment: perhaps you missed a step - the only unknown is `User` - perhaps you've created that wrong ... I take it there are fields called `username` and `password`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js and Passport Object has no method validPassword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565059/node-js-and-passport-object-has-no-method-validpassword)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs because .validPassword(password) is not a function under 'user'. Simple example:

```
//I use this code on google.com main page.
var logo = document.querySelector("#hplogo");
logo.validPassword(""); // -> Error: .validPassword is not a function
// here I declare function under 'validPassword'
logo.validPassword = function(pass){
console.log("Validate password", pass);
};
logo.validPassword(""); // -> message: 'Validate password',''
```

So i guess you are missing function itself.